# Edit distance for n-grams?

Tags: python, nlp, n-gram, edit-distance

I want to know if we can find the edit distance (or something like that) between n-grams?

I'm creating a topic model for which I'm receiving topics of the following form:

```
Topic #5:
[u'hour block', u'block hour', u'package hour', u'hour block hour']
Topic #16:
[u'schedule block', u'block schedule', u'able schedule block', u'open schedule']
```

So like for the above example in topic #5 the first two bigrams are same except words in reverse order, I want to find such ngrams (like by finding some sort of a weight between each ngram in that topic) and group them under one (say represent `'hour block'` and `'block hour'` by `'hour block'` only)

How do I do that?

Comment: You do it the same way as you would for word–word edit distance: instead of a sequence of characters (= a string) you feed in a seqence of tokens (you need to tokenise the n-grams).

Comment: Have you had a look at the [std lib's difflib module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html)? The [SequenceMatcher examples](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-examples) could be interesting for you.

Comment: Agree with @lenz, just one observation, the regular edit distance algorithms include inserts, deletes and edits; if you also need swaps you are looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance